# How to get the difference between two values on a time series in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, csv, date

In Python, it is easy, but in JavaScript, it is giving me such a headache.

I am using Chart.js, D3 and Date-FNS. I am using CSV. You can check my CSV file [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gusbemacbe/4b7cb4efa65c2d4b0087f943e6fb4f87/raw/a912904246321798a5fcb0772c11e4208cf629ce/covid-19.csv).

I would like to get the difference of cases or deaths between each day, so theoretically I could get the number of new cases or deaths per day instead of total cases. I mean to resample every 2 days using a arithmetic operator. It's just subtracting that is giving me such a headache.

Similar to Python's Pandas' `diff()` in the questions:

- [Is there a function to get the difference between two values on a pandas dataframe timeseries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488407/is-there-a-function-to-get-the-difference-between-two-values-on-a-pandas-datafra),
- [Calculating difference between two rows in Python / Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114512/calculating-difference-between-two-rows-in-python-pandas)
- [How to calculate day's difference between successive pandas dataframe rows with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534152/how-to-calculate-days-difference-between-successive-pandas-dataframe-rows-with).

I was suggested to use `map()` and `reduce()`, but nothing worked.

Inspired by [Subtract values in column in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100720/subtract-values-in-column-in-js), I tried:

```js
  const DailyDeathsData = dates.map((d, pair) =>
  {
      var firstVal = parseInt(d.totalDeaths[pair]);
      var secondVal = parseInt(d.totalDeaths[pair + 1]);
      var daily = (firstVal > secondVal) ? firstVal - secondVal : secondVal - firstVal;
      return daily;
  });
```

But it returned all zeros.

Then, inspired by [JavaScript go through array and subtract each item with next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260142/javascript-go-through-array-and-subtract-each-item-with-next), using `slice`, `map` and `reduce`:

```js
const DailyDeathsData = dates.slice(1).map((v, i) => v.totalDeaths - dates[i].totalDeaths);
```

It also returned all zeros.

Then, using `reduce`:

```js
const DailyDeathsData = dates.reduce((v1, v2) => { return v1.totalDeaths - v2.totalDeaths });
```

But it did not display.

Comment: Just a side note: if `d.totalDeaths[pair]` represents the number of deaths from the beginning of the records to day X and `d.totalDeaths[pair + 1]` represents the number of deaths from the beginning of the records to day X+1, the check `(firstVal > secondVal) ? ...` is pointless as `secondVal` will always be greater than or equal to `firstVal` (unless people begin coming back from death as zombies XP).

Comment: I used this condition because of negative subtraction, for example, 21 deaths - 23 deaths = -2 days. I have just removed this condition and tested. It returned all zeroes.

Comment: Is `d.totalDeaths[pair]` the *total* number of deaths from day 1 to day X? If it is, you know for a fact that the *total* number of deaths from day 1 to day X **cannot** be greater than the number of deaths from day 1 to day X+1. The *total* number of deaths from day 1 can only increase or stay stable as time passes; it cannot decrease. What can decrease is the *daily* number of deaths.

Comment: Is it something like this, you are trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/hk5ts7nz/

Comment: I compare the graphs results in JavaScript and Python. Exactly, @secan. Put your answer that I conclude. I also used `d[pair].totalDeaths` too but I understood now, that it had to be `dates` instead of `d`, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, you can do something similar to:

```js
const data = [{
    city: 'Aparecida',
    date: '2021-01-04',
    totalDeaths: 21,
    totalCases: 781,
    totalRecovered: 724,
    totalBeds: 13,
    intubated: 1
  },
  {
    city: 'Aparecida',
    date: '2021-01-05',
    totalDeaths: 22,
    totalCases: 822,
    totalRecovered: 724,
    totalBeds: 8,
    intubated: 3
  },
  {
    city: 'Aparecida',
    date: '2021-01-06',
    totalDeaths: 22,
    totalCases: 831,
    totalRecovered: 724,
    totalBeds: 11,
    intubated: 2
  },
  {
    city: 'Aparecida',
    date: '2021-01-07',
    totalDeaths: 22,
    totalCases: 847,
    totalRecovered: 724,
    totalBeds: 15,
    intubated: 2
  },
  {
    city: 'Aparecida',
    date: '2021-01-10',
    totalDeaths: 22,
    totalCases: 857,
    totalRecovered: 724,
    totalBeds: 16,
    intubated: 4
  }
];

const totalDeathsCurve = data.map((item, index) => {
  if (index === 0) return 0;
  return data[index].totalDeaths - data[index - 1].totalDeaths
});

console.log(totalDeathsCurve);
```

In a nutshell, you map your data and:

1. set the `totalDeaths` of the first item as your starting point (0)
2. subtract from the current item's `totalDeaths` the previous one to obtain the daily total

Anyway, please be aware that if you have missing days in your data (and you have; for exemple you go from 2021-01-07 directly to 2021-01-10) the difference will not represent an actual *daily* difference; it will merely represent the difference with the previous entry