# javascript Get the difference between an element of an array and the previous one

Tags: javascript, arrays, difference, milliseconds

Assuming I have an array of milliseconds values like this:

```js
   const array = [
     1633236300000,
     1633244100000,
     1633248000000,
     1633252500000,
     1633287600000,
     1633291500000
   ]
```

How can I get the difference between an element of an array and the previous one?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What should the output be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript go through array and subtract each item with next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260142/javascript-go-through-array-and-subtract-each-item-with-next)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You can use old-style for loop with the starting index as `1`

```js
const array = [
  1633236300000, 1633244100000, 1633248000000, 1633252500000, 1633287600000,
  1633291500000,
];

const result = [];
for (let i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
  result.push(array[i] - array[i - 1]);
}

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const array = [
  1633236300000, 1633244100000, 1633248000000, 1633252500000, 1633287600000,
  1633291500000,
];

const result = array.map((n, i, src) => n - (src[i - 1] ?? 0)).slice(1);

console.log(result);
```

**3)** You can also use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here

```js
const array = [
  1633236300000, 1633244100000, 1633248000000, 1633252500000, 1633287600000,
  1633291500000,
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr, i, src) => {
  if (i !== 0) acc.push(curr - src[i - 1]);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array by slicing from the 2nd element (index 1) to the end, and map it. Take an item from the original array, using the index (`i`), and substract it from the current item (`t`).

```js
const array = [1633236300000,1633244100000,1633248000000,1633252500000,1633287600000,1633291500000]

const diff = array.slice(1)
  .map((t, i) => t - array[i])
  
console.log(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the item in the array, then subtract the item at the previous index from the current one:

```js
const array = [
  1633236300000,
  1633244100000,
  1633248000000,
  1633252500000,
  1633287600000,
  1633291500000
]


const num = 1633291500000;

const diff = num - array[array.indexOf(num) - 1];

console.log(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function getDiff (n) {
  if (array.indexOf(n) === 0) return 'no previous time'
  return n - array[array.indexOf(n) - 1]
}

const d = getDiff(array[0])
console.log(d)
```